# Where to specify the activity to invoke when my app icon is pressed in Phone Contact

Tags: android

I have added a connection to my app for an existing contact and my app's icon shows up for that Contact in the native Contacts App. However, when I touch my app icon, Contacts App crashes. Please let me know which part of code I should paste to help you guide me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I am not getting any log. It is the native Contacts app that is crashing when I touch my app icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey add this code into AndroidMainfest.xml

suppose you want open first activity on icon click.then add this intent filter into that activity

```
       <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">

            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.package_name.activity_which_you_want_to_open" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. A basic question - does the mimetype have to start with "vnd" ? I mean "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." ? Can it be vnd.android.cursor.item/com.xxx.yyy.zzzzzz" ?

Comment: This field defines a custom MIME type (recognizable by the type/subtype pattern).

Android suggests you use vnd.android.cursor.dir/... as the first part for any kind of "directory listing" (multiple items) and vnd.android.cursor.item/... as the first part for any kind of single item.

For the subtype, it's again suggested to start it with vnd. and then add something like your reverse domain name / package name, e.g. vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.mydomain.myapp.mydata

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added intent filter to your app like one below, If not add it to your main activity in Manifest.

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes I have added it and the app as such is working fine, the problem is when I try to press the App icon from a Contact.